# Why isn't the move constructor being called?

Tags: c++, move-semantics, rvalue-reference

I am new to C++ and am trying to understand rvalue references and move semantics.

I have written a simple class, Class, which includes a method, fun, which creates an instance of the class in its body and returns it. The class has a copy constructor, a move constructor, a (copy) assignment operator, and a (move) assignment operator.

The following

```
Class obj2(obj1.fun()); // ??

obj3 = obj2.fun();      // (move) Assignment operator
```

neither calls the copy constructor nor the move constructor and calls the (move) assignment operator, respectively.

How does obj2 get created? Why doesn't

```
Class obj2(obj1.fun());
```

call the move constructor,

```
Class obj2(std::move(obj1.fun()));
```

does call the move constructor, and

```
obj3 = obj2.fun()
```

calls the (move) assignment operator (without needing to write `std::move(obj2.fun())` like in the move constructor case)?

Many thanks!

Comment: This question is asked [very frequently](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBF_deDE833DE833&biw=1600&bih=789&sxsrf=ALeKk01tl1aGRpTI0Y_2bMmOUanFbfkJzA%3A1607705232529&ei=kKLTX_TlH4S-kwXGwqHACg&q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+%22c%2B%2B%22+move+constructor+not+called&oq=site%3Astackoverflow.com+%22c%2B%2B%22+move+constructor+not+called&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzoECAAQR1Cw7P8BWITAgAJg_8SAAmgCcAJ4AIABhwGIAZkUkgEEMjEuNpgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXrIAQjAAQE&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwj07abasMbtAhUE36QKHUZhCKgQ4dUDCA0&uact=5). Did you check the other posts?

Comment: _"I prefer Remy Lebeau's answer below."_ Fine, I'm closing your question as duplicate though, so that others researching in future will have a chance to find the link to that duplicate (which has a few answers more).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why doesn't `Class obj2(obj1.fun());` call the move constructor

Because of [Copy Elison](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision).  The compiler sees that `fun()` returns a temporary object, and that temporary will only be used to initialize `obj2`, so the compiler *optimizes* the creation of `obj2` by eliminating the temporary object altogether and allowing `obj2` to be created directly inside of `fun()` itself, thus there is no need for a copy/move operation when `fun()` exits.

> `Class obj2(std::move(obj1.fun()));` does call the move constructor

Because you are forcing it with the explicit `std::move` type-cast, so the compiler can't optimize the creation of `obj2` via Copy Elison, so it has to allow `fun()` to return a temporary object, which you are then moving into the `obj2` constructor.

> `obj3 = obj2.fun()` calls the (move) assignment operator

Because `obj3` already exists before the assignment.

> without needing to write `std::move(obj2.fun())`

Because `fun()` returns a temporary object, which is an rvalue, so there is no need to explicitly type-cast it to an rvalue when calling a move assignment operator.